# How to disable and enable when option buttons are checked

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I have two groups of option buttons lets say qtr1 and qtr2 code is as follows:

`<input type="radio" id="qtr1" name="qtr1"  value="Quarter-1">Quarter-1
<input type="radio" id="qtr2" name="qtr2" value="Quarter-2">Quarter-2
<input type="radio" id="qtr2" name="qtr2" value="Quarter-3">Quarter-3`

now when i have checked qtr1 and when i check for qtr2, qtr1 is still checked. How can i enable or disable option buttons using jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by option buttons? where is the respective code? [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Do you want only one button active? That is called a radio button.  See `type="radio"` in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you work with option/radio button keep **same name** for all option button then you not need to Implement any javascript/jquery for that ..

```
    <form>
<input type="radio" id="qtr1" name="qtr1"  value="Quarter-1">Quarter-1
<input type="radio" id="qtr2" name="qtr2" value="Quarter-2">Quarter-2
<input type="radio" id="qtr2" name="qtr2" value="Quarter-3">Quarter-3
    </form>
```

here is your script using jquery

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){

  $("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', false);

  $(this).prop('checked', true);

});
```

Exmple [JS-BIN](http://jsbin.com/zedixuva/1/)

Comment: Hi Anant, Looks good. But here i have three different values and two different names for radio buttons specified. So could you suggest based on my requirement

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() { 
           var gname=$(this).attr('name');
        if(gname=='qtr1')
        {
            $('input[name="qtr2"]').prop('checked', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('input[name="qtr1"]').prop('checked', false);
        } });
```